# Data recovery after user profile corruption on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery

I'm away from home for college, and my computer back home has been having some issues. My dad took it to a computer store, and apparently the user profiles somehow got corrupted, so they're locked out of the computer. This is a Windows XP box, but I changed the default administrator account password, so that backdoor isn't a possibility.

Now, that computer's HDD has a whole bunch of data on it which my dad would hate to lose, so I suggested that they take the HDD out, plug it into some other computer, and just copy all the data off that way (keeping in mind that the data itself wasn't encrypted). However, the computer store people said that wouldn't be possible unless they had the administrator account password (which I can't remember for the life of me), and that they'd either have to reformat and reinstall Windows, or else use some complicated sounding recovery process costing a decent amount of money. That sounds like complete BS to me, but I'm not 100% sure about it, so I thought I'd get some more opinions. Could someone more knowledgeable about this stuff suggest a good course of action to take?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we retrieve data from an unbootable computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/359745/how-do-we-retrieve-data-from-an-unbootable-computer)

Comment: That computer repair place is totally incompetent, don't go back, you don't need a password when copying data from a hard drive, and they should have reset the windows password while it was in the original PC, then they could have logged into Windows to repair the profile...http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a livecd or liveusb - i like xubuntu for this, but any major distro with NTFS 3G would be good.

If you want to play it safe, make a copy of the drive with ddrescue.

Next, mount up the drive with ntfs-3g and see if you can copy files off it, if so, well, you're good - assuming the actual data you want isn't corrupted, you should be able to get it out.NTFS-3g is third party, but on occation can retrieve data off drives windows can't read

Next, you would probably want to try changing the admin password with the [offline password changer](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/), (which should let you log in as the admin), and if you can, delete and create the offending accounts

Comment: Perhaps, it's worth noting, that the actual referenced package is probably called **gddrescue**. However, the executable inside is called **ddrescue**. Also, maybe it would be slightly more reasonable to use **dd** instead, as it has a simpler, more obvious syntax than the aforementioned, which is more suitable for advanced needs (from my experience, it does not recover any more or less data than **dd** though). In case of bad sectors, arguments to **dd** should be **conv=noerror,sync** and **oflag=direct**.

Comment: there's multiple rescue oriented varients of dd, and there are supposedly some advantages to the recovery oriented version if there's damage to the media.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. So I take it that my idea of just plugging the HDD into a second computer as a secondary drive isn't feasible. Out of curiosity, why is that so? I understand that file ownership is built into NTFS, but since my files themselves weren't encrypted, and I had simple file sharing enabled, what exactly would prevent it from working? Since I'm not in town and won't be for a while, I want to give my parents as low-tech a solution as possible, which is why I'm asking. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @m68z8mi, it is most likely feasible, but that's just an assumption that might not reflect the reality, as in case the drive has some data corruption in crucial areas - that might cause a reading anomaly with **Windows**, which will result in _freezing/hanging_ when the drive is to be accessed. If that is the case, as **JG** has pointed out - **ntfs-3g** has a higher chance of properly mounting the filesystem, thus enabling you to get the data off. So, if the drive is actually fine and only corrupted on the software level of the OS (profiles), then the low-tech solution is the passwd reset app

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: yes, **dd_rescue** (which is script-based from what I know) and **ddrescue**. Neither of them is able to actually recover any more data than **dd**. The only added extra value is the logging ability (adds resume) and a few tricks with reverse-reading/multiple passes. It still takes the **same** amount of time encountering a delay when trying to go through a bad sector.

Comment: you could. I just find that NTFS-3g works better in *some* situations (actually annoyingly so, its saved me a few file recoveries, when i was hoping for a chance to play with software by simply letting me copy off the files), and a livecd is a lot simpler than removing the drive and putting it in another box. Honestly, i'd even skip the ddrescue bit if you're sure its a software issue. Once files are recovered, changing the password should let you log into the system, and fix things from there.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help everyone, you guys are awesome.