# My computer won't boot up, how do I transfer files to an external hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, boot, backup

I'm having problems booting Windows 7, and I need to extract files from the computer's hard drive onto an external hard drive.

When I insert the Windows 7 DVD, I get two options, formatting and repairing. When I try to repair the system, the process runs very slow and I am asked to reboot the computer when finished, even though the problem is not solved.

How do I transfer data off my system's hard drive onto an external hard drive? My computer is a Dell laptop running Windows 7.

Comment: Also: [How do we retrieve data from an unbootable computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/359745/how-do-we-retrieve-data-from-an-unbootable-computer)

Answer (score 3):

At this stage it is often easiest to get a blanket "no" or "maybe" and some guidance about valuable terms to google for, and that is how this question reads.

Blanket answers:
Is there a way to back up your files with just the disc you have? No. Is there a way to back up your files? Maybe. Can you determine if you can back up your files? Yes. Is there a way to copy the data from your internal drive to the external drive and boot from it without further work? No.

There are ways to attempt to copy files to an external hard disk without booting the OS on the internal hard disk. However, so many things could be causing your computer not to boot that we can't answer what files can be copied, what files may be corrupt, whether a new install of windows 7 would boot or be stable, whether you need hardware replaced, etc.

Look into Ubuntu live CDs and USBs and how to copy files using them. In many cases it is as easy as dragging and dropping files from onee windoe to another. Following those directions will answer many of the uncertainties in the paragraph above. In particular, add the step of reading the SMART data from your internal drive. In the best case, you will be able to back up your files.

Edit: 
As pointed out in comments, running a check on an already failing drive can make it worse. Definitely back up your files first! Afterward, safely eject the external drive then open Disk Utility from the menu if using Ubuntu, then click the button to read the SMART data. That way your files are safe and you know whether it's safe to go to the effort of reinstalling Windows on that drive.

Speaking of data safety, do run a virus scan on your backed up files with an updated and patched version of Windows before opening them!

Comment: I'd skip the SMART check unless there's read errors or noises/clicks. So far just looks like windows is messed up, but continued "very slow" repairing attempts could push a "weak" drive over-the-edge into failure, and/or overwrite wanted data.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a little scary if you've only used Windows, but get a Linux "live" DVD or CD. That will let you boot from the optical disk without changing the hard drive. You'll be able to plug in an external drive and then copy files using the File Manager (graphical user interface; not exactly Windows but close enough for comfort) or, for extra points, the command line.

It doesn't matter much which Linux distro you use for this. I'd recommend one of the more popular ones such as Fedora or Ubuntu.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Install Windows 7 on your SSD with your setup CD. Just one day, you don't need to activate the system with key.
1. Restart the computer, enter the BOIS, setting CD-ROM or USB as the first boot devices. Then install Windows 7 on your SSD. Now you can do anything with your HHD, except migrating OS, software or fixing your unbootable OS.